# derivative of a function fitted using a neural network

Tags: neural-network, derivative, sigmoid

This question is quite general and mathematical.

I'm using a neural network with a single hidden layer (10 neurons) to approximate a function with 2 input and 2 output variables.
The sigmoid function is used as activation function.

Later, I'm using the derivative for something else. I approximate the derivative with a numerical method. This method uses outputs of the neural network.

I was wondering if the derivative of the approximated function can be obtained easily as the learning algorithm uses derivatives for every neuron.

I could get rid of the numerical method for the derivation if there was a simple way to get the derivative out of the neural net.

I'm thinking of the chain rule, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go and how to use it correctly.

Comment: The derivatives that are calculated during backprop are wrt the parameters, not the inputs. I'd say use numerical methods as you say with slight perturbations on the input to the neural net.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a programming question. Computing derivatives is just applying the chain rule as you say.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro: What's the purpose of your comment? If I got it right, it's a general statement on derivatives which is not really related to the specific situation in a neural network and therefore not helpful.

I would be thankful if you could explain the value of your statement related to the question.

Comment: @user3932876 SO is a programming website, and your question is not actually about programming. If you had code, then a specific answer could be made. My point is to strengthen that what you were asking is completely mathematical.